# Does CLOCK_TIMESTAMP from a BEFORE trigger match log/commit order *exactly* in PG 12.3?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, triggers, audit-trail

I've got a Postgres 12.3 question: Can I rely on `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()` in a trigger to stamp an `updated_dts` timestamp in *exactly* the same order as changes are committed to the permanent data?

On the face of it, this might sound like kind of an silly question, but I just spent two tracking down a super rare race condition in a non-Postgres system that hinged on exactly this behavior. (Lagging commits made their 'last value seen' tracking data unreliable.) Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible for `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()` to not match the order of changes recorded in the WAL perfectly.

It's simple to see how this could occur with `NOW/TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as they're returning the transaction start time, not the completion time. It's pretty easy, in that case, to record a timestamp sequence where the stamps and log order don't agree. But I can't figure out if there's any chance for commits to be saved in a different order to the `BEFORE` trigger `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()` values.

For background, we need a 100% reliable timeline for an external search to use. As I understand it, I can create one using logical replication, and a replication-target side trigger to stamp changes as they're replayed from the log. What I'm unclear on, is if it's possible to get the same fidelity from `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()` on a single server.

I haven't got the chops to get deep into the Postgres internals, and see how requests are interleaved, nor how granular execution is, and am hoping that someone here knows definitively. If this is more of a question for one of the PG mailing lists, please let me know.

-- Thanks

Below is a bit of sample code for how I'm looking at building the timestamps. It works fine, but doesn't prove anything about behavior with lots of concurrent processes.

```
---------------------------------------------
-- Create the trigger function
---------------------------------------------
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS api.set_updated CASCADE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.set_updated()
RETURNS TRIGGER

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
   NEW.updated_dts = CLOCK_TIMESTAMP();
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION api.set_updated() IS 'Sets updated_dts field to CLOCK_TIMESTAMP(), if the record has changed..';

---------------------------------------------
-- Create the table
---------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS api.numbers;

CREATE TABLE api.numbers (
    id          uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT extensions.gen_random_uuid (),
    number      integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    updated_dts timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT 'epoch'::timestamptz
);

---------------------------------------------
-- Define the triggers (binding)
---------------------------------------------
-- NOTE: I'm guessing that in production that I can use DEFAULT CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() instead of a BEFORE INSERT trigger,
-- I'm using a distinct DEFAULT value, as I want it to pop out if I'm not getting the trigger to fire.
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_api_number_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON api.numbers
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_updated();

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_api_number_before_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON api.numbers
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_updated();

---------------------------------------------
-- INSERT some data
---------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO numbers (number) values (1),(2),(3);

---------------------------------------------
-- Take a look
---------------------------------------------
SELECT * from numbers ORDER BY updated_dts ASC; -- The values should be listed as 1, 2, 3 as oldest to newest.

---------------------------------------------
-- UPDATE a row
---------------------------------------------
UPDATE numbers SET number = 11 where number = 1;

---------------------------------------------
-- Take a look
---------------------------------------------
SELECT * from numbers ORDER BY updated_dts ASC; -- The values should be listed as 2, 3, 11 as oldest to newest.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot depend on `clock_timestamp()` order during trigger execution (or while evaluating a `DEFAULT` clause) being the same as commit order.

Commit will always happen later than the function call, and you cannot control how long it takes between them.

But I am surprised that that is a problem for you. Typically, the commit time is not visible or relevant. Why don't you simply accept the `clock_timestamp()` as the measure of things?

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer. And, yes, we would be fine with the timeline as it is, except that we're doing pulls from Domo, and want to pull only newly changed data. Domo provides an internal variable for tracking the max or last value of one column., If I've got any lagging timestamps, just as the pull begins, they'll be committed after the pull is initiated, and never make it into Domo. it's got to be a rare circumstance, but with a chance greater than 0. It matters as any reports/extracts based on the two systems must agree exactly, or else clients ask why they're not identical.

Comment: How about using some grace time? Only pull rows with a timestamp older than a second or so. Then there is little risk that an uncommitted transaction with an earlier timestamp is still lurking.

Comment: Yes, building in some padding/wiggle room would be just the thing. Like with log analysis tasks, it's nice to have a bit of a buffer to slight clock drift, and other anomalies. In this case, that's a feature request for the folks at Domo, as they don't currently support it. Good idea though, I'll submit it.